# conditional evaluation of functions

Tags: c++

Ok, this might be a stupid question, but I completely don't understand chapter 12.1.6.2 - conditional evaluation under constexpr functions of the c++ programming language. This is the whole very short text.

> A branch of a conditional expression that is not taken in a constexpr
>   function is not evaluated. This implies that a branch not taken can
>   require run-time evaluation. For example:
>
> ```
> constexpr int check(int i)
> {
>     return (low<=i && i<high) ? i : throw out_of_range();
> }
>
> constexpr int low = 0;
> constexpr int high = 99;
>
> // ...
> constexpr int val = check(f(x,y,z));
> ```
>
> You might imagine low and high to be configuration parameters that are
>   known at compile time, but not at design time, and that f(x,y,z)
>   computes some implementation-dependent value.

[Source for context](http://books.google.com/books?id=0klsAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA313&lpg=PA313&dq=A+branch+of+a+conditional+expression+that+is+not+taken+in+a+constexpr+function+is+not+evaluated.+This+implies+that+a+branch+not+taken+can+require+run-&source=bl&ots=S1m8XjAO0N&sig=jmMyUE6sKR0e-xcur3U_c41KpiM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z9cqVL6XJo2LyASl7oLIAw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=A%20branch%20of%20a%20conditional%20expression%20that%20is%20not%20taken%20in%20a%20constexpr%20function%20is%20not%20evaluated.%20This%20implies%20that%20a%20branch%20not%20taken%20can%20require%20run-&f=false)

I tried running the code above to try to more understand the explanation but I'm getting an error. Can someone provide a clearer explanation?

Edit: I created a program to test this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

constexpr int low = 0;
constexpr int high = 99;

constexpr int check(int i) {
    return (low<=i && i<high) ? i : throw out_of_range();
}

constexpr int f(int x, int y, int z) {
    return x*y*z;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int val = check(f(2,2,2));
    cout << val << '\n';
}
```

It won't run:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::out_of_range::out_of_range()' //I'm really surprised at this
     return (low<=i && i<high) ? i : throw out_of_range();
error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr int check(int)' not a return-statement
 }
error: 'constexpr int check(int)' called in a constant expression
  constexpr int val = check(f(2,2,2));
```

Comment: Note `f` must also be a `constexpr` function.

Comment: You might want to see if `static_assert()` can be of use.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: @dgnuff `static_assert` _requires_ a constant expression, so if you added it to `check` you could not call `check` at run-time with non-constant arguments. The point of the example above is that it is a valid run-time check, that can also be used to initialize constexpr variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that a conditional branch in a constexpr function is allowed to use non-constant expressions (i.e. ones requiring run-time evaluation, such as throwing exceptions) as long as that branch is never taken when the function is called in a constant expression context.

So it's OK to call `check` to initialized the `constexpr` variable `val`, as long as the arguments to the function are constant expressions, and the condition `(low<=i && i<high)` is true.

If the arguments are not constants, the function call is not a constant expression and so can't initialize a `constexpr` variable.

If the condition is false the function needs to take the false branch, which needs to throw an exception, which requires run-time evaluation, so the function is not a constant expression, and so cannot initialize a `constexpr` variable.

When the argument is a constant expression, the compiler knows at compile-time whether the branch will be taken, so as long as the condition is `true` it can completely ignore the `false` branch, and doesn't complain that throwing exceptions is impossible at compile-time.

When the function is called at run-time, it can have any arguments, and the `false` branch can be taken and the `throw` will be evaluated as for a normal (non-constexpr) function.

Comment: thanks I understand now. But I want to test it and it won't run? Please check my edit.

Comment: `std::out_of_range` does not have a default constructor, you need to pass it a string, e.g. `throw std::out_of_range("i must be low <= i < high")`